# Chroot in Go using syscall is giving error

Tags: go, system-calls, containerd

I'm trying to write a container daemon in Go as a part of my college project and for some reason, `Chroot('/to/a/directory')` is giving me an error:

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
```

I have tried using `syscall.Chroot()` and the Chroot field in SysProcAttr, but as it might have been clear, the error remains.

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and my Go version is *1.13.5*

Edit:

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    switch os.Args[1] {
    case "run":
        run()
    case "child":
        child()
    default:
        panic("Too less arguments")
    }
}

func run() {
    fmt.Printf("Running: %v\n", os.Args[2:])

    cmd := exec.Command("/proc/self/exe", append([]string{"child"}, os.Args[2:]...)...)
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
        Cloneflags: syscall.CLONE_NEWUTS,
    }

    cnr(cmd.Run())
}

func child() {
    cmd := exec.Command(os.Args[2], os.Args[3:]...)
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
        Cloneflags: syscall.CLONE_NEWUTS,
    }

    syscall.Sethostname([]byte("container"))
    syscall.Chroot("/home/utsav")
    syscall.Chdir("/")

    cnr(cmd.Run())
}

func cnr(err error) { //Check and Run
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve], it's impossible to tell what's wrong without it.

Comment: What happens when you do `chroot /to/a/directory` in a terminal? (not via go)

Comment: Are you sure the user the script is running as has access to that directory?

Comment: Chances are that after you did you `chroot` you forgot to also do a `chdir`, leaving your *current* directory unreachable from inside your chroot environment.

Comment: @Tomor chroot command works fine inside the bash. The specified directory is set as root.

Comment: @pwaterz, yes, I'm sure that the script has access to the directory.

Comment: @torek, I did `chdir` after `chroot`. Though that should not make any difference since I'm working as a root user.

Comment: In that case, I refer you back to @MarcoBonelli's first comment: provide a [mcve].

Comment: @torek, I did provide some lines of code in the question. Would you please be so kind as to look at it?

Comment: Those lines by themselves look OK. But that's not a [mcve]: an example that reproduces the problem would be something someone else could compile and run and observe the `shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory` output. You'll need a `package main`, imports, etc., before we can even compile this.

Comment: I suppose you need to `syscall.Chdir("/home/utsav")`  before `syscall.Chroot('/home/utsav')` (not after). Take a look at C-example for chroot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946063/howto-enter-into-chroot-environment-from-c

Answer (score 0):

Chroot requires additional setup to to the environment.

If you use chroot(). One of the major consequences is that many (most, all) of the commands normally available are not available unless you make them available in the new environment.

You may need parts of /dev, /bin, /etc, /usr, /lib (and probably others too) installed appropriately under the new root directory

Kind of like:

```
RUN mkdir /chroot && \
    cp -r /bin /chroot/ && \
    cp -r /sbin /chroot/ && \
    cp -r /usr /chroot/ && \
    cp -r /etc /chroot/ && \
    cp -r /lib /chroot/ && \
    cp -r /lib64 /chroot/ && \
```